# Visual Composer не может обновится, ругается на неактивированную тему The7?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Всем привет, сайт построен на теме The7, после отключения плагина Composer - он не дает себя включить, пишет - не могу обновить из-за неактивированной теме The7 - при этом ложиться весь сайт постороенный с помощью этого Visual Composer. Есть ли какие либо безболезненные решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Отвязать композер от темы хуком или попробовать активировать через wp-cli

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте найти строку `add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_set_as_theme' );` и удалить её, чтобы VC был у вас не как часть темы, а как отдельная сущность.